# Validation rule prevent user deleting record in pipelines?

Tags: validation, validation-rule, delete

I need to write a validation rule that prevents the user from deleting any pipeline records that they did not create? How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Hi Paul, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. What have you tried so far? Have you done any research into this problem space? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I can hopefully save you a bit of time and effort here with the following statement: Validation rules can't prevent record deletion.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to validate deletion is with an `Apex Trigger`. To validate a record and prevent its deletion, you need to call `addError`.

The most basic working structure would look like:

```
trigger MyObject on MyObject__c (before delete)
{
    for (MyObject__c record : trigger.old)
    {
        if (UserInfo.getUserId() != record.CreatedById)
        {
            record.addError('Some validation message');
        }
    }
}
```

A few things to note:

- You should read all the way through [Trigger Frameworks and Apex Trigger Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices)

  - Consider implementing a `Handler Pattern` and/or `Service Layer`
- Consider moving the error message to a [`Custom Label`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cl_about.htm&language=en_US&type=0) so that it can be configured

Answer (score 0):

Assuming pipeline is a custom object, you could accomplish this by setting the `organization-wide defaults` for the object to `public read-only` and unchecking the '`Grant Access Using Hierarchies`' checkbox.

You would need to build sharing rules to grant edit access to others.  Sharing rules do not grant delete or transfer permission, so that would still be controlled.

Only the owner will be able to delete (other than users with the modify all data system permission or those with modify all on the object).

One other edge case is users with the 'transfer records' system permission.  Those could transfer the record to themselves and then delete it. That would apply with the trigger solution as well, so you would need to determine how best to address that.

**UPDATE**
just noticed that you indicated preventing deletion of records they did not *create*.  I thought it was for records they did not *own.*  Often the owner is the same as the creator, but depending on your use case my proposed solution may or may not work!